# Spring, Hibernate, JPA, ManyToOne with added where clause or Differentiator column without the inhertiance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

For simplicity, here is a smaller version of my model:

```
@Entity
public class Request {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;



    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EntityType entityType; //Differentiator
    private String entityId; //The identity of the column it refers to.



    private Timestamp date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    public enum EntityType {
        TypeOfRequestObject, AnotherType, Unknown
    }

}
```

Now, using JPA I've come up with some Queries that allow me to access the data, but it's ugly and somewhat hardcoded, What I would prefer is something along the lines of a Where Query in the ManyToOne/OneToMany annotations that would also allow cascading.

```
@ManyToOne(where="entityType='AnotherType'")
```

Have you guys heard of anything like this?
I can appreciate that ManyToOne may not be the correct approach.

I'm using standard Hibernate 5, JPA and Spring Boot, all of which is requested through a Jackson Message Converter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some [filters](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/hibernate-filter-and-filterjointable-annotation-example) with this filter tou can access to collections using some specific criteria or conditions.

If you give more info about the tecnologies that you are using maybe we can give a more specific answer.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for! I've updated my answer with the technologies used.